# Convert list of pairs to a table in shell without using awk

Tags: linux, shell, posix, data-processing

I have a tab-delimited list of pairs like this:

```
apple  yellow
orange green
apple  red
pear   blue
apple  yellow
apple  yellow
```

I want to convert it, using Linux command-line tools, to table:

```
       yellow green red blue
apple     3     0    1   0
orange    0     1    0   0
pear      0     0    0   1
```

Can I do this with minimum scripting by hand?

*Note:* I know how to *code* this, thank you, the question is about pre-existing tools, possibly with *minimal* script glue. And `awk` programs, unless they are very short, count as "scripting" for that matter.

*Note 2:* This is a **learning** question. I do not care much if solution is short or long (shorter are preferable though). I want to *learn* other ways of solving this problem.

If I wanted to solve this problem in the fastest way, I would not ask this question here, I would go and spend 30 seconds on writing three lines in the language I know best.

Comment: Yep, just use `awk`, the only other solutions are more verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk:

```
awk '{num[$1,$2]++; fruits[$1]=1; colors[$2]=1}END{for(i in fruits) {for(j in colors) printf("%d ", num[i,j]); printf("\n");}}'
```

PS. As an afterthought... You can look into `join` utility. Paired with counts by fields maybe this will do the trick. But i promise it will be hairier.

PPS. I'll add it here, as comment box is too cramped.
Alexander, you need something to run on POSIX system. There's some amount of logic involved in the task. Be it put into a script of a tool, or a long pipe with several commands - the amount stays roughly the same. As `awk` was designed to produce reports, it's the good tool in this case.
Basically you don't have many means to format the text - it's `printf` utility/builtin or `awk`. In the former case it means about three lines in the script and some more to produce the result. So i think thare's no shorter way. But's kind of theoretical from my limited albeit prolonged experience. I would also like to know an easier way if there's one, i like to learn too:)

Comment: Ah, but `awk` scripting is still scripting :-)

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: it's considered _minimal_:) I think that output as a table shall involve some scripting anyway. Let's see if some bash gurus say something. I deal in portable programming so for me `awk` is the best option in this case.

Comment: I think bash is not the best tool for this job, but in perl or python it is a couple lines.

Comment: @pooh: Well, no problem with that. It is just that I want to explore how to do this *without* scripting — to improve my knowledge of other command-line tools, not only awk or whatever other programming language I can use.

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: I dare to say that no shorter solution exists within POSIX.2.

Comment: @Paulo: I do not argue with that. But I want to know how to do this in bash. :)

Comment: @pooh: About 'it's considered *minimal* ' — maybe, but it is not *glue*. :-)

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: Ah, because you said `Linux command-line tools`... So decide what exactly do you need - pure bash, or command-line tools, or maybe perl? In pure bash it's easy - there are arrays too. But see - if you do it in bash, you'll need one cycle to get the input, and second to print the results. It will anyway be the same amount of code roughly.

Comment: @pooh: well, I do need anything that I able to run from shell on a POSIX system, as long it does not involve scripting (say, nothing more than `awk '{print $1}'` or using `perl` to get a nicer regexp than `sed`)

Comment: @pooh: sorry, that was an error on my side, I do *not* mean bash script.

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh - part of learning about bash / unix tools is to know what they are good for and what they are not good for, the wonderful thing about Unix is that it is developed from necessity, and `awk` came about to deal with the type of problem you've posted here.  I'd just like to add, do you spend hours trying to put shoes on your face and underpants on your feet, so that you can walk on your ears?  Because what you seem to want to do is about as absurd.

Comment: @Slomojo: Trying to get more knowledge about other existing solutions is never absurd.

Comment: Ah, well, but after googling up more, I'm ready to admit that there is no other sane way. :-)